# How to determine the model order from ACF and PACF?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

Can someone help me out with this?
I have a first difference TS that has a constant mean around zero, but the variation differs for some periods. 
[image]

I get the following ACF and PACF
[image]

What can be a possible model for this TS?
Can I say a ARIMA(0,1,1) is suitable?

Comment: post your data and I will try and help you as the acf/pacf analysis is only valid under certain circumstances